# copy rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 automatically whenever there is a new row added in sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could be done more simply I think but since you asked for how to do this with VBA here is how to do it with VBA.

```
'This goes in the Sheet1 code window
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rws&
rws = Sheets("Sheet1").Range([A1], ActiveSheet.usedRange).Rows.Count
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

For i = 1 To rws
    For n = 1 To 30
     Sheet2.Cells(i, n).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, n).Value
    Next n
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will replicate the active rows and the columns 1-30 to Sheet2 in an excel file, to make the code replicate more columns edit the value for For n = 1 To 30.

Edit: Edited after Jean-François Corbett kindly pointed out that I forgot to mention that I only included 30 columns.

Edit2: Code to insert a row instead of directly copying the values - note that this code just inserts a row and the copies the data i tested it with a simple =Sum and it seems to work well.

```
Dim curRow As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rws&
rws = Sheets("Sheet1").Range([A1], ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Rows.Count
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

For i = 1 To rws
    For n = 1 To 30
        If i > curRow Then
            Sheet2.Cells(i, n).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
        Sheet2.Cells(i, n).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, n).Value
    Next n

Next i
curRow = rws
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So each time *any* cell changes, *everything* gets re-copied to Sheet2?

Comment: thanks it really help, but i need that rows be inserted in sheet2 .let me explain : in my seconde sheet, i have somme formula in line 20, so if ther's more than 20 lines copied, my formula's line will be ecrased ) ?